# Minimal transversal of a Hypergraph

Tags: data-mining

Hi This is my first post, so please go easy on me. I tried going through an algorithm Dualize and Advance for generating maximal frequent item sets. I considered an example as follows

**Transactions**

1. abcde
2. ace
3. bd
4. abc

and minimum frequency threshold as 2.

Now, I have a problem understanding how to generate 'minimal transversals' part of the algorithm.

I know that transversal is a subset of vertices of the hypergraph that intersects every hyper edge. So the initial set of minimal transversals should be {a,b,c,d,e} if I am not wrong.

Can you please explain me this part of 'minimal transversal' w.r.t the transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ll try to answer my question.
At the end of first iteration of the algorithm and for the given transactions, {abc} is emanated as maximal frequent itemset. Here is how I understood,

minimal transversal X  = S1' = {a,b,c,d,e}

S2 = {abc} is maximal and S2' = {de}

Find minimal transversal of S2' which is {d,e}

Now, X = {d,e}, consider 'd' ,

S3 = {bd} is maximal and S3' = {ace}

Now, consider 'e'

S4 = {ace} is maximal and meanwhile I get {ad} , {be} ,{cd} and {de} as minimal transversals which are infrequent.

Answer (score 0):

A subset T of V is a transversal (or hitting set) of H if it
intersects all the hyperedges of H,

'minimal transversal' -> the smallest possible set that we get.

Also, we enforce ordering in our algorithm a>b>c>d>e

**Iteration 1:**

```
S1 = {}
S1' = {abcde}
Tr = {a,b,c,d,e} [All nodes are required to cut Si']
```

**Iteration 2:**

```
S2 = {abc}
S2' = {de}
Tr = {d,e} [Two nodes are required to cut Si']
```

**Iteration 3:**

```
S3 = {abc, bd}
S3' = {de, ace}
Tr = {e, cd, ad} [Three nodes are required to cut Si']
```

**Iteration 4:**

```
S4 = {abc, bd, ace}
S4' = {de, bd, ace}
Tr = {de, cd, ad, be} [Four nodes are required to cut Si']
```

All minimal transversals Tr are infrequent so the algorithm **ends**.